# Anything wrong with moving from a washable mesh HVAC filter to disposable?

Tags: hvac, filter, air-filter

Currently my HVAC system has this inside it: https://www.discountfilters.com/air-filters/bryantcarrier-kfafk0212med-2-pack/p110138/

It's a washable mesh basically...and it doesn't seem to offer much protection from...well...anything. Seems like the only thing it could stop is a golf ball. Says "Merv 4".

I want to get a Merv 13 disposable filter to hopefully help with my seasonal allergies...found one on Amazon that will fit (it has a weird size...couldn't find something that size at Lowes). Seems much more substantial...looks pretty solid from the pictures. My question is will this hurt the furnace at all with the (I imagine) reduced airflow from the new heavier filter?

Answer (score 2):

You may have the issue of a reduced flow rate as the system has been designed so that all the components “match”.

This could cause poor performance or even overheating as the motor works harder.

You could contact the manufacturer for their advice.

Comment: I agree with some systems getting the very high end filters can damage the system and or create errors.

Comment: As a follow-up to my question...bought the Merv 13 filters anyways and I can attest they did seem to cause strain on my HVAC. It was much louder when they were installed like it was laboring to work. So much for trying to filter allergens.